# How to use 'heroku run python manage.py migrate' after deploying from the Github?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I wrote an app with Django(1.10.6) and deploy it to heroku through automatic deploys from Github. However, after the deployment, the project on Heroku has some bugs in Database:

```
ProgrammingError at /
relation "sport_facility" does not exist
LINE 1: ...lity"."open_at", "sport_facility"."close_at" FROM "sport_fac...
```

Thus, I deploy through Heroku Git and it works well. I checked the activity for the previous app, and found there was no `migrate` when deploying from Github.

I wondered how I could be able to run heroku command(like `heroku run python manage.py migrate` or `heroku ps:scale web=2`, etc) from command line for the app deployed from Github?

Comment: It looks like you can't: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#what-about-schema-migrations

Comment: Thanks. That is a sad news : (

Answer (score 0):

See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44268769/):

Basically:

> open your `Procfile` and add this line: `release: python manage.py migrate`. This will tell Heroku to migrate before deploying a new version of your code.