# Deploying Django app to Heroku via CircleCI: How to migrate database?

Tags: django, heroku, circleci

How can I run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` automatically when deploying a Django app to Heroku via CircleCI. It seems all commands run local to CircleCI, but not on the deployed application in production.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`python manage.py makemigrations` should be running locally, and you may commit the migration files along with the code.

Regaridng the migrations, open your `Procfile` and add this line: `release: python manage.py migrate`. 
This will tell Heroku to migrate before deploying a new version of your code.